# Visual Studio Code bracket auto completion

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-completion, square-bracket

This has been annoying me for a while. VSCode doesn't let me type a closing bracked or parenthesis or the like ( `")", "]", "}"`) when there is already a closing symbol of the same type.

In this WEBM you see me try to set another set of brackets and VSCode skips the closing bracket that I typed. This is extremely annoying.
[WEBM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCdPr.jpg)

How do I disable this behaviour in VSCode? (Or correct it, so VSCode closes the inner bracket for me.)

Edit: I know I can disable auto closing brackets in VSCode with `"editor.autoClosingBrackets": false`. But I don't want to disable it altogether. I just want to disable the overtyping.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**TL;DR:** As of June 2019, it's not possible to disable only the overtyping part of the *autocloseBrackets* function. You can only disable auto 
bracket closing altogether.

[Some people](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/37315#issuecomment-421682846) suggest using the [TabOut Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=albert.TabOut) for Visual Studio Code to tab out of quotes, brackets, etc.

---

Ok, so what I found out over at the VSC Github is this:

> [...] This can be turned off via editor.autoClosingBrackets. The feature
>   consists of multiple parts:
>
> - one is that when ( is typed, the result is (|).
> - the other part that is hit here, is that when ) is typed and ) follows the cursor, ) will be overtyped.
>
> The feature is implemented language agnostic and looks only locally at
>   the next character. It does not count brackets to determine if the
>   code is "bracket unbalanced".

(Source: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/35799)

At the moment, it's not possible to fix this, without losing the auto 
bracket closing feature. The above thread has since been closed. New one is here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/37315 , but no patch has come out yet.

Comment: Maybe it helps, i'm using Ctrl+RightArrow or Ctrl+End to move out of auto-closed brackets depending on keyboard layout.

Answer (score 5):

I face the same issue,
It's because of the GIT COPILOT once I uninstall and restart the VS CODE it's working properly now

Answer (score 0):

Editor::Auto Closing Overtype does what you want now.